# Fragment is not null when onCreate is called due to orientation change

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity that adds a fragment to it's layout in it's onCreate.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    //R.id.fragment_container refers to a framelayout in R.layout.new_layout 
    MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) fm
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, new MyFragment());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

The first time the activity is created and onCreate is called, fragment is null, so a new MyFragment is added to R.id.fragment_container. I expect the same scenario when onCreate is called after an orientation change but in this case, fragment is not null indeed. I actually want to know exactly happens when orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

When orientation changes, the entire screen is refreshed. **Android restarts the entire running Activity.** When this happens, onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate(). You can take care of orientation changes by doing a couple of things. One way to handle this restart is to utilize onSaveInstanceState(). Another (**easier**) way to handle this problem is to disable orientation changes all together. You can do this by going into your AndroidManifest file and adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` or `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` under the activity section.

[Handling Runtime Changes in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)